# Find and append to file without loading it in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, stream

Im writing a simple XML file for logging that looks like this :

```
<root>
 <objects>
 </objects>
</root>
```

The file is created the first time like this

```
using (xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePathAndName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("objects");
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlWriter.Close();
}
```

Now I need to place objects(serialized data contracts in string format) within the objects tag **without loading it to memory**.

I have found a lot of suggestions on how to do this but all loads the entire file into memory and thats no good when the files is large.

My thought is this :

1. Open file with some kind of reader
2. Search from end of file to `</objects>` tag
3. Store the index and close the reader/file
4. Open the file again but this time as a writer
5. Write the serlized datacontract to the index(just before the
6. Close file

I'm however not sure how to do this properly in C#?

Comment: Just how large *are* the files here? (I would personally use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlTextWriter` in general, as it makes for much cleaner code.) Are you just afraid of the inefficiency of loading the file, or do you know that it's definitely not an option?

Comment: I'd usually recommend against using XML for logging, precisely because you can't simply append each new entry but must instead overwrite part of the existing file each time a new entry is created. Is there any reason it can't be a simpler format and then transformed into XML when XML is required?

Comment: Can you split it into [multiple files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31114/Split-large-XML-files-into-small-files)?

Comment: @JonSkeet The method for logging to file is generic and are used by multiple parts of the application. This method take the serialized object as a string and then the path and filename so save to. If the file already exists it checks the size and if its okay it appends. One file will not be bigger then 100 MB but there might be several different files at the same time. So, reading the entire file in to memory each time I need to add a happening does not feel right. I dont see how Linq to XML really helps me, its just another way to manipulate XML from what I know?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever XML have a couple of good features, its simple to deserialize to objects, its easy to inspect without special tool, just drag it to a webbrowser and the formation is fixed. I dont see why it would be bad for logging? Is not WCF logging using XML? My thought (see main post) looks easy but yet its hard to find info about how to do this. I have worked with files manually with C++ where it was easy to find and and at specific places, C# seems to be more complicated?

Comment: @lloydm, If you look at my answer to JonSkeet you will understand that multiple files is not a easy way to go in this case. I dont really see why I would split it up? Is it the size you are thinking of? I really don´s see why a file needs to be read in to memory just to add specific text to a specific index in the file. It should not be hard to find the last object end tag and add text just before that? But maybe that's not possible with C#?

Comment: Have a look at Windows version of [tail](http://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/) to read in last lines.

Comment: I found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx  and tried the XML Inclusion Techniques but when dragging the Logfile.xml to the browser the events is never shown? Suspect that browsers dont know about the future?

Comment: I'm with Damien. Log to a text file in CSV format. Put your timestamps in canonical format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) and if you need to put nasty things in fields use base64 encoding. Appending to a text file is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me in this case was XML Inclusion Technique, it is not perfect but the login is much simplier. I can use appendToFile instead of manipulate or read into memory.